# Updating Composer autoload files without `composer update`?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on a project which has a lot of dependencies which I personally control. Whenever the namespace mapping changes in a requirement, I need to run `composer update` to refresh the Composer autoload file so the namespace mappings can be picked up.

However if I'm making changes in the `vendor/` directory directly, there's no need to check out the latest versions through `composer update` -- all I need is to refresh the autoload file. For a project with dozens of requirements hosted on GitHub, `composer update` can take minutes.

Is there any way to get `composer` to refresh the autoload files *without* having to run `composer update`?

Answer (score 93):

`composer install` and/or `composer dump-autoload` would do the same.
([dump-autoload documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-))

Comment: This doesn't actually pick up any changes in the `vendor/` directory. e.g. if I change the autoloader namespace in `vendor/*/*/composer.json`, neither of these commands pick it up.

Comment: You should not directly modify your vendor directory like that.

Comment: Instead, you should make the change in the repository of the dependency and then only update that dependency (`composer update [packagename]`)

Comment: Don't use the classmap autoloader, use PSR-4 or PSR-0, and plan ahead accordingly. A package usually should be responsible for adding classes in one namespace. That way you'd never have to update the autoloader when adding new classes in the existing namespace.

Answer (score 10):

Could you modify `vendor/composer/installed.json` and then run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Please explain that further. How does this work different than the answer by Sven which is more than five years old?

Comment: When you must change some `composer.json` inside `vendor`, simply running `dump-autoload` doesn't pickup the changes, may sometimes be needed for local debugging before deploying, for that: search inside `installed.json` for the changed package and update the autoload part manually with your intended changes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PSR-0. If so, you should switch to PSR-4 as it does not require rebuilding the autoloader when you add, remove or change classes in existing dependencies.

If you add additional top level dependencies, whether it's manually or using `require`, then you will have to run `composer update`.